# How to remove all contents of a folder in an S3 bucket except 1 directory

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, github-actions

Each deploy, a new directory is created within an `assets/` folder in my S3 bucket, and when the deploy is completed, I'd like to keep the latest version, but remove *all other* folders.  I can't seem to get the `aws s3 rm` command to property do this...

```bash
$ export MOST_RECENT_DEPLOY=$(aws s3api list-objects-v2 --bucket $AWS_CDN_BUCKET --prefix assets --query 'reverse(sort_by(Contents,&LastModified))[0]' | jq -r '.Key | split("/") | .[1]')
$ echo "Pruning all asset folder except .../assets/$MOST_RECENT_DEPLOY"
$ aws s3 rm "s3://$AWS_CDN_BUCKET/assets/" --exclude $MOST_RECENT_DEPLOY --recursive --dryrun
   Pruning all asset folder except .../assets/2023.03.30-a861c982
   (dryrun) delete: s3://cdn.mysite.com/assets/2023.03.30-a861c982/
   (dryrun) delete: s3://cdn.mysite.com/assets/2023.03.30-a861c982/my-file.txt
   (dryrun) delete: s3://cdn.mysite.com/assets/2023.03.31-1231423/
```

No matter what I do the directory I want to keep continues to show up as being deleted.  What am I missing with my exclusion?

Comment: I would presume that the `--exclude` parameter value is incorrect. Try "$MOST_RECENT_DEPLOY/*" or "assets/$MOST_RECENT_DEPLOY/*".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue here is the `MOST_RECENT_DEPLOY` variable, the S3 bucket string, and the lack of wildcards. AWS S3 does not have folders but rather keys for each object. The `--recursive` flag allows prefix matching on those keys.

By passing in `"s3://$AWS_CDN_BUCKET/assets/"`, the `rm` command will start looking under prefix `assets` in the `AWS_CDN_BUCKET` bucket. Then it will exclude just an object named in the `MOST_RECENT_DEPLOY` variable. No wildcards are used in the `rm` command, so it is just excluding `s3://cdn.mysite.com/assets/2023.03.30-a861c982` in the example. Try adding a forward slash and a wildcard to the end of the `MOST_RECENT_DEPLOY` variable, so the exclude covers everything under the  `MOST_RECENT_DEPLOY` prefix.

I find this documentation to be helpful as well: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3/index.html#use-of-exclude-and-include-filters

Comment: :facepalm: you're right.  Thanks you!